# Select BLOB data from MySQL and Display on HTML page slow

Tags: php, mysql, select, blob

I have a webapp, where I need to display PDF files which are stored as Mediumblob in MySQL DB. Problem is that, the displaying process works but is very slow.
html jQuery function code:

```
        function ordRes() {
                 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "resultOrdPDF.php",
            data: {
                "tid": 13411
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#resDivID").html('nothing to show');
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                    $('#resDiv').html(msg);
                } //success end
        }); // Ajax Call end
    }
```

resultOrdPDF.php code:

```
<?php
$otsitav=$_POST['tid'];
$db=new mysqli('192.168.1.x','un','pw','newpms');
$query="SELECT data FROM pf_scanOrd WHERE filename=".$otsitav;
$result=$db->query($query);
$num_results=$result->num_rows;
if($num_results>0){
for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++){
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo  '<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($row['data']).'" type="application/pdf" style="height:1000px;width:100%"></object>';    
}}
else{
    echo "<h2>No information</h2>";
    }
$result->free();
$db->close();
?>
```

This code works, but how to speed up blob selection process?

Comment: What is slow? Reading from MySQL? Downloading the binary? Rendering it in the browser? Also what reasons do you have for storing a file in a database vs just as a file in the filesystem?

Comment: @Halcyon, slow is fetching from DB. Today this app reads pdf from filesystem, but i need to do performance improvements, because in filesystem there would be up to 100 000 PDF files. Therefore i thought it would be better to store pdf's to MySQL DB.

Comment: Of course it’s slow ... base64 encoding generates about one third bigger output than the actual raw data, plus you are cramming multiple of those into a single document via Data URIs ... all in all this just results in “a sh*tload” of data you are sending to the client. If I wanted to improve this, I’d start by NOT using Data URIs, but by serving each PDF via a separate request.

Comment: _"because in filesystem there would be up to 100 000 PDF files. Therefore i thought it would be better to store pdf's to MySQL DB"_ - I strongly doubt this will actually improve things, rather the opposite. If you don’t have this running on a Raspberry Pi, the file system should have no problem handling that number of files - provided you organize them a little better than dumping them all into one single folder.

Comment: @CBroe, indeed i run this app on raspberry g3 with touchscreen, and on asus tinker board with larger touchscreens. PDF files are stored on central fileserver. I think how can i improve file system storage system.

Comment: _"PDF files are stored on central fileserver"_ - that should be able to handle this without much problems then, no?

Comment: @CBroe, it works this way OK today.